# How to rotate two flexbox rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two flexbox rows that look like this.

[image]

Is this possible to rotate them 90 degres so that are located next to each other? I need them to look like this.

[image]

```
<ul class="flex-container longhand">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex-container longhand">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.longhand {
  flex-flow: wrap row;
}

.flex-item {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Put them into an additional container, and rotate that …?

Comment: I tried to apply CSS *transform: rotate(90deg)* but with no luck.

Comment: @CBroe Good idea, let me try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `.flex-container` with additional div, then make some transformation on it.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.longhand {
  flex-flow: wrap row;
}

.flex-item {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="flex-container longhand">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="flex-container longhand">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set second `flex-container` as column using `nth-child selector` as below,

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container:nth-child(2){
  flex-direction:column;
}
.longhand {
  flex-flow: wrap row;
}

.flex-item {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-container:nth-child(2) > .flex-item{
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container longhand">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex-container longhand">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<ul class="flex-container longhand">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex-container longhand">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent
{
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.longhand {

  flex-flow: column;
}

.flex-item {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```

I created a parent so that I can put the two flex containers next to each other. Then I rotated each flex item individually.